# check if collection is empty in playframework template

Tags: java, playframework

I have a `Shopcart` having `cartitems`(A java `Set`) which I need to render in my play application template.The `shopcart` is available at template since the controller action sets it in `renderArgs(shopcart)`.
I would like to display a message telling the user whether the cart has any cartitems .Currently I am doing it like this

```
...
your cart #{if shopcart.cartItems} has some#{/if} #{else}#no{/else} items
...
```

This conditional seems a bit convoluted..Is there some tag /extension which can tell if the collection is empty or not?

thanks in anticipation

Comment: is it's simple java set then you can do if(cartitems.size()==0){}.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a tag to do it in template..not in javacode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always make a custom template:

```
#{conditionalMessage truth:'Has stuff' lies:'Has nothing' condition:shopcart.cartItems.size() == 0 /}
```

Then implement the conditinalMessage template do the logic in your example.

**app/view/tags/conditionalMessage.html**:

```
#{if _condition}
    ${_truth}
#{/if}
#{else}
    ${_lies}
#{/else}
```

see this page for more details: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates

Comment: I wish people would upvote answers more as well as approve them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check empty list by,

```
#{if shopcart.cartItems != null && shopcart.cartItems.size()>0}has some#{/if} #{else}#no{/else} items
```

Comment: why can't you just do 'shopcart.size() == 0'?

Comment: updated the answer, I was an impression that, when we don't have option like el( `shopcart.cartItems.length`), I thought we may not check size in play.

Comment: Yeah, in EL you have limitations. But in Play 1.x it's just Groovy. So you have a lot more flexibility in what you can and can't do.